# How can I return a whole hash map in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, reference, mod-perl, perl-data-structures

I have a hash called

```
%values
```

Now I want to return the whole hash in a subroutine

```
sub getvalues {
  return $values;
}
```

But then I got an error, because $value needs a definition and my program stops. If I'm using

```
sub getvalues {
  return %values;
}
```

it seems to work, but my program is very slow and don't get further... So how can I return the whole map?

Comment: I think you, refer perl reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to return the hash reference instead of hash,what you need to do is

First stote the hash into the hash ref then return it like

```
sub getvalues {

    my %values = (test => "SO");

    my $values = \%values;

    return $values;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you tell me what the line '%hash = (test => "SO");' stand for? So can I copy and paste the whole routine or have I to change some values?

Comment: @ManuelHinz: I have just provide you the example, %hash is like your %values hash as you mentioned in the question.

Comment: @NikhilJain why not just return the reference directly: `return \%values;` ?

Comment: And I have another small question. I want to share this variable between two moudles. So mod1 contains the hash and mod2 will get access via mod1->getvalues(). Is it possible with this solution?

Comment: @ManuelHinz Of course it's possible. You should try it yourself with a simple test.

Comment: @chrsblck: Ofcourse we should return the reference directly, I just tried to explain to OP that's why I mentioned the hash and then show OP that how OP can store the hash into hash ref, becuase sometimes it's very difficult for the newbie to understand the things if we just show the one liner.

Comment: I made the hash lexical, or the same reference would be returned every time the function was called.

Comment: if we return the reference of temporary hash map as above will it not get destroyed at the end of the function and the caller will have invalidated reference ?